# To encounter someone/something or to encounter with someone/something?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I have seen both forms and I don't know which one is the more appropriate (if there is a difference).

The actual sentence in which I want to use it is "particles can encounter (with) the atoms of the material".

But I'm also interested in the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, it's the verb form, and you would **not** use "with".

If it was the noun form, you could use "with", like

"I had an *encounter with* an old girlfriend on saturday".

See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/encounter